# Binding WPF with Caliburns only works for some of the properties

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, caliburn.micro

For some reason my bindings in my program doesn't work for all my properties.

#### View

```
    <StackPanel
        Grid.Row="0"
        Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,5" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <TextBlock
            Margin="10"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Text="Camera device: "
            Foreground="White"/>
        <ComboBox
            Name="CameraDevices"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ConnectedDevices}"    <!-- This binds fine -->
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCamera}"     <!-- This binds fine -->
            Width="168"
            VerticalAlignment="Center">

            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />      <!-- This binds fine -->
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>

        </ComboBox>

    </StackPanel>

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="SelectedCamera_Name" Foreground="White"/>   <!-- This binds fine -->

    <StackPanel
        Grid.Row="2"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        Orientation="Horizontal" Width="100" Margin="58,0,59,0">

        <Button
            x:Name="ToggleButton"
            Width="80"
            Margin="10"
            Height="25"
            Content="Start" <!-- This binds to the function Start in my viewmodel (not shown)-->
             />

    </StackPanel>


    <Border
        x:Name="devicecamContainer"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Grid.Row="3"
        BorderBrush="Black"
        BorderThickness="0">

        <Image Source="{Binding Path=CameraImage, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  VerticalAlignment="Top" /> <!-- DOES NOT WORK -->

    </Border>
    

</Grid>
```

#### ViewModel

```
public class UIViewModel : Screen
{
    #region Properties
    public BindableCollection<CameraModel> ConnectedDevices { get; set; }

    private CameraModel _selectedCamera;

    public CameraModel SelectedCamera
    {
        get { return _selectedCamera; }
        set
        {
            _selectedCamera = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedCamera);
        }
    }

    private ImageSource _cameraImage;

    public ImageSource CameraImage
    {
        get { return _cameraImage; }
        set { _cameraImage = value;

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Updated " + _cameraImage);
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CameraImage);
        }
    }

    

    public UIViewModel()
    {

        ConnectedDevices = new BindableCollection<CameraModel>(CameraDevicesEnumerator.GetAllConnectedCameras());

    } 

    public async void ToggleButton() //It's the same button for start/stop
    {
        
        if (_started == false)
        {
            _started = true;

            var selectedCameraDeviceId = SelectedCamera.OpenCvId;

            if ((_camera == null || _camera.CameraDeviceId != selectedCameraDeviceId)) 
            {
                _camera?.Dispose();
              
                _camera = new CameraStreaming(cameraDeviceId: SelectedCamera.OpenCvId);

            }

            try
            {
                await _camera.StartCamera(true);
                await _ultraSound.StartCamera(false);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);

            }

            LoadingVisibility = false;
           
        }
    
        else
        {
            _started = false; // To be implemented

        }
    }
```

(Both have been edited down a bit, to only show relevant info)

The CameraImage is set in a helperclass, but It's set to the correct value, and updated as expected. But for some reason it doesn't show in my view.
I've tried binding it in a few different ways:

```
<Image Source="{Binding=CameraImage" />
<Image Source="{Binding=CameraImage, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
<Image Source="{Binding Path=CameraImage}"   />
<Image Source="{Binding Path=CameraImage, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"   />
<Image x:Name="CameraImage" />
```

#### CameraStreaming - *Helper class*

```
public sealed class CameraStreaming : IDisposable
{

    private System.Drawing.Bitmap _lastFrame;
    private Task _previewTask;

    UIViewModel viewModel = new UIViewModel();

    private CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource;
 

    public int CameraDeviceId { get; private set; }


    public CameraStreaming(int cameraDeviceId)
    {
                   CameraDeviceId = cameraDeviceId;
    }

    public async Task StartCamera(bool crop)
    {
        
        if (_previewTask != null && !_previewTask.IsCompleted)
            return;

        var initializationSemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(0, 1);

        _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        _previewTask = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                var videoCapture = new VideoCapture();

                if (!videoCapture.Open(CameraDeviceId))
                {
                    throw new ApplicationException("Cannot connect to camera");
                }

                using (var frame = new Mat())
                {
                    while (!_cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        videoCapture.Read(frame);

                        if (!frame.Empty())
                        {
                            if (initializationSemaphore != null)
                                initializationSemaphore.Release();

                                _lastFrame = BitmapConverter.ToBitmap(frame);
                               
                                var lastFrameBitmapSource = _lastFrame.ToBitmapSource();
                                lastFrameBitmapSource.Freeze();
                                viewModel.CameraImage = lastFrameBitmapSource;                                                                                                  

                        }

                       
                        await Task.Delay(10);
                    }
                }

                videoCapture?.Dispose();
            }
            finally
            {
                if (initializationSemaphore != null)
                    initializationSemaphore.Release();
            }

        }, _cancellationTokenSource.Token);

   await initializationSemaphore.WaitAsync();
        initializationSemaphore.Dispose();
        initializationSemaphore = null;

        if (_previewTask.IsFaulted)
        {
            // To let the exceptions exit
            await _previewTask;
        }
    }
```

### EDIT! Posted my CameraStreaming-class

None of them works. My other bindings, which are in the same ViewModel works just fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You aren't showing the code that actually updates the CameraImage property. Maybe that code operates on some other instance of the view model.

Comment: As a note, `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` is pointless here. It only has an effect in TwoWay of OneWayToSource Bindings.

Comment: I've updated the post. It now contains the CameraStreaming helper class and the method called in teh ViewModel

Comment: `UIViewModel viewModel = new UIViewModel()` creates a new view model, i.e. a different instance than the one to which the view is bound. You should pass a reference to the existing view model instance to the CameraStreaming class and use that.

Comment: Oh God! I completely overlooked that! It fixed everything :D Thank you so much!
If you put it as an answer, I will be sure to accept it.